# Matching Regular Expressions java when word contains embedded &

Tags: java, regex

I use a regular expression to match words (and not match embedded strings) that looks looks like this:

```
word.trim().matches("(\\w+)(\\.|\\?|\\!|\\<)?");
```

This works great if the word is a string like this word = " blue ";

But it fails if the word has an embedded &, or any special character, like this
      word = " A&P ";
or this 
     word = " A-P ";

How can I alter my regular expression so that it picks up certain special characters like "&" and "-"

Comment: the special chars must be in between. Right?

Comment: `word.trim().matches("([-&\\w]+)([.?<!])?");`

Comment: `/([\w&-]+)([.?!<])?/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Why `([.?<!])?`?

Comment: @TheLostMind It's a more compact version of `(\\.|\\?|\\!|\\<)?`.

Comment: `?`, `.` looses it's special meaning within a char class.

Comment: @Biffen - Nope. I meant. *why not include it as part of the first charset*?

Comment: @TheLostMind In OP's regex it has to come *after* the word.

Comment: @Biffen - It matches `b&` not sure if the OP wants that :P

Comment: @TheLostMind They didn't exactly specify otherwise.

Comment: @Elliott There seems to be some confusion about what you want the regex to match. Could you supply some samples, preferably both positive and negative ones?

Comment: @TheLostMind `([.?<!])?` === `[.?<!]?`

Comment: @Bohemian - yes.. But not captured :P.. I am really confused with what the OP wants.. So, I can't say much :P

Comment: The Op does say "embedded" so that suggests, between, but not starting with and not ending with special characters & and -.

    (\\w+([-&]?\\w+)*)[.?!<]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems about the simplest:

```
str.matches("(?i)[a-z]+([-&][a-z]+)?[.!?<]?")
```

Also note the re-phrasing of your alternation to a character class, since each term was a single character and being a character class you don't even need to escape dot or "?".

The `(?i)` means "ignore case".

I'm not confident about the "<" being a legitimate "word ending"; you might consider removing it from the regex.